# Does the sigma algebra over the real line contain the singleton sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Sigma algebra over real line contains all the open sets, their unions and complements. Does this also contain a singleton sets? If yes what is the measure of these singleton sets? 1 or 0? I read that all countable sets of real line have measure zero. On the contrary, I expected countable sets to have a measure equal to the number of elements in the set. Can somebody explain what my misunderstanding is? One more thing is how is it related to probability theory. For example, normal distribution is defined on the entire real line. Does it assign a zero probability to a single point on the real line? or is it not defined because singleton set is not a part of sigma algebra?

Comment: How can we explain the fact that sum of probabilities is 1 over the real line considering real line is made of infinite singleton points, but probability assigned to a single point is zero?

Comment: If $S$ is a set and $P$ a probability measure then $P(S)=\sum_{s\in S}P(\{s\})$ only "works" if $S$ is *countable*. If it is not then such sums are not defined and we work with integrals. We are forced to make a distinction between countable and uncountable sets. Also a PMF is a density wrt the counting measure and a PDF is a density wrt the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singletons are closed, hence are complements of open sets.

So "yes", they are contained by the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ generated by open sets.

The question: "what measure do they have?" can only be answered if a measure is specified (which is not the case in your question).

If you are thinking of e.g. Lebesgue measure then the answer is $0$, if you are thinking of e.g. the counting measure then the answer is $1$.

Normal distribution is continuous so that it assigns probability $0$ to every singleton (and consequently to every countable subset of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: If I think of using counting measure, what is the measure of an interval set like [0,1]?

Comment: Counting measure gives value $+\infty$ to every uncountable set.

Comment: but measure should be a finite value, right?

Comment: Can you also explain my question in the comment section under the question?

Comment: *Probability measures* only give *finite* values, but the counting measure is *not* a probability measure (neither is the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Can you give any example of a non-measurable set on real line w.r.to the Lebesgue measure? Can I say that an interval set is non-measurable w.r.to the counting measure? Also it'd be great if you can point to any source where there is a good explanation of measure theory and it's relation to probability theory.

Comment: Google on "Vitali set" and have a look on e.g. Wikipedia. Every subset of $\mathbb R$ is measurable wrt counting measure. For finite sets its value is the cardinality of the set and for infinite sets its value is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}$ is open, it is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. So is its complementary, which is $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton sets are closed, so these are Borel sets.  (There are many different $\sigma$-algebras.  The smallest sigma algebra containing the open sets is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.)  The Borel measure of a singleton is $0$.  The probability assigned to a singleton by the normal distribution is $0$.